# referencing other class methods without creating a new instance

Tags: c#, class, reference

I have a class by itself called `clientChat` that does basic network stuff. I have several other classes linked to different window forms. In my first form I have a variable referenced to the chat class like so:

```
clientChat cc = new clientChat();
```

Everything works okay their, the class has been initialized and everything is in motion. After the first forms is done performing it's duty I bring up my second form that's obviously linked to a new class file.

Now my question is, how can I reference what's going on in the `clientChat` class without setting a new instance of the class? I need to pass data from the form to the `networkstream` and if I create a new instance of the class wouldn't that require a new connection to the server and basically require everything to start over since it's "new"? I'm a bit confused and any help would be great, thanks. C# on .NET4.0

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into the Singleton design pattern. Mr Skeet has written a good article on how to implement it in C# [here.](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) (Just use version 4. its the easiest and works fine =) )

Comment: This does not seem like an appropriate place to use the singleton pattern.

Comment: Why not? The OP seems not to want to create two network connection to the server, but refer to the first initialized connection in different contexts. I've used the Singleton pattern in these cases. Was this inappropriate?

Comment: The approach to pass references around quickly gets out of hand if the project grows. When I used it, in time every method and class needed to be passed one instance of chatClient. =)

Comment: What happens if you extend the software to allow two client connections?

Comment: @cdhowie: Good point. Only the OP can tell if this is a likely scenario, but he should be aware of that limitation.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an instance of `clientChat` in the beginning of your program and then, simply pass its reference to the classes that need it.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you would either:

1. Create the object from the code that creates and shows both forms, and pass a reference to that same instance to both forms, or:
2. If you create the second form from inside the first form, pass a reference to the instance referenced by the first form to the second somehow (via a property or a constructor, for example).

Answer (score 0):

In additional to @Jens's answer, there are 5 approaches on the linked page, while I think we have the 6th using [`Lazy<T>` in C# 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx)

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private Singleton() { }
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> m_instance = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());
    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return m_instance.Value;
        }
    }
}
```